# How to Access corrupted Raspberry Pi SD card using Ethernet Connection

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-4, linux, kernel

I have Raspberry PI with Corrupted SD card, showing Kernel Panic Message, is there any way i can access it without removing SD card from SD card SLOT, raspberry pi is connected with Ethernet, which is connected to Windows PC.

Comment: `without removing SD card` ... why?

Comment: because the device is used in  remote place, and many more devices are there, every time personally going there and remove sdcard is a difficult task, we have planned to update it using android app sending ssh scripts and commands, so without remove we have to update ,

Comment: is Ethernet to C type USB adapter helpfull ?? so that we can connect to android phone or laptop to get device identification as drive and can be format corrupt SD card ?? , any use of such please guide

Comment: maybe you could do network boot ... it depends on which version of Pi you have ... you used misleading tags

Comment: Without removing SD card because pi board is covered for data security reason, Only Ethernet is open in remote Pi Device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the kernel panic stop the operating system loading?

If the operating system has not been loaded you can not access the SD card from the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: yes, kernel panic stops the OS loading, i want to format the corrupt sdcard through DD command or any other way, so that i can switch to network boot for pi3b+ and for pi4 i can modify the eeprom to boot network then i can correct the corrupted SD card with New OS

Comment: If the operating system has not been loaded you can not access the SD card from the Raspberry Pi.